# selectedRowInComponent for UIPickerView is returning random rows only when spun and not selected. What is happening?

Tags: ios, uiview, uipickerview

I have a double picker and two NSInteger variables that update what row each component of the picker is on. In the iPhone simulator (I haven't tested on an actual iPhone) the numbers are fine if I pick the row (ie click below or above), however when I spin I receive row numbers that are typically a couple off from the actual. Here is what I have:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

if (component == kSuitComponent) {
    UIImage *image = self.suitImages[row];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self theSuitRow];
    return imageView;
}
else {
    NSString *text = self.cardNumber[row];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self getCardRow];
    label.text = text;
    return label;
}
}
 -(void) getCardRow {
    cardRow = [_doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kCardNumberComponent];
}
-(void) theSuitRow {
suitRow = [_doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kSuitComponent];

}
```

Comment: viewForRow:forComponent: is used to populate the rows with views, and is called multiple times -- you shouldn't use that to get a selected row. Is there a reason why you're not using pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    if (component == kSuitComponent) {
        UIImage *image = self.suitImages[row];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        return imageView;
    }
    else {
        NSString *text = self.cardNumber[row];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = text;
        return label;
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == kCardNumberComponent) {
        cardRow = row;
    } else {
        suitRow = row;
    }
}
```